# Mercurial - block access to a branch using ACL extension on Windows

Tags: windows, security, mercurial, branch, acl

I am trying to deny everyone commit access to a branch using ACL on Windows but can't quite seem to figure it out.  According to the little documentation I've found this should work.

My hgrc file:

```
[extensions]
hgext.acl=

[hooks]
pretxncommit.acl = python:hgext.acl.hook

[acl]
sources = commit

[acl.deny.branches] 
default = *
```

Shouldn't this deny everyone commit access to the default branch? I tried and now every commit, no matter the branch give:

```
error: pretxncommit.acl hook failed: config error - hook type "pretxncommit" can
not stop incoming changesets
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: config error - hook type "pretxncommit" cannot stop incoming changesets
```

Leads me to think I configured it wrong, but it's pretty much exactly how they do it in the [AclExtension documentation](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/AclExtension.).

Comment: Your `hgrc` works as expected for me on WinXP and Mercurial 1.7 (I just upgraded!).  What version of Mercurial do you have?

Comment: @Niall C. I was under 1.5.1, the one that came bundled with TortoiseHg when I installed a while back.  I upgraded to 1.7 and it worked fine.  Wasn't clear I needed to upgrade from the doc.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the relevant code from acl.py:

```
if hooktype not in ['pretxnchangegroup', 'pretxncommit']:
    raise util.Abort(_('config error - hook type "%s" cannot stop '
                       'incoming changesets nor commits') % hooktype)
```

Which I would think checks after the "`.acl`" from your hook name is removed, but perhaps in your version of mercurial (what version?) it isn't?

Try changing your `[hooks]` section to just this:

```
[hooks]
pretxncommit = python:hgext.acl.hook
```

the `.acl` is only necessary when you have multiple hooks of the same type.

Comment: This is under 1.5.1 (bundled with TortoiseHg), I tried removing the .acl and still got the error.

Comment: I just updated to 1.7 and it worked.  Both did actually, with and without the .acl